# How to display third party widget on a Laravel site?

Tags: laravel, widget

How can I display a third party widget in Laravel?

My Laravel code:

```html
@section('content')
<section>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1>We Guide You Trough!</h1>
      <p>Interested in crypto currencies, blockchain, crypto mining?</p>
      <p>Then CryptoMonkey is a perfect place to start!</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg green signup" data-target="#signupModal" data-toggle="modal">Sign up-It's free</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
@endsection
```

I would like to put this widget under the jumbotroon.

But it doesn't display.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  baseUrl = "https://widgets.cryptocompare.com/";
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
  var embedder = scripts[ scripts.length - 1 ];
  var cccTheme = {"General" :
    {"background":"#000","priceText":"#fff"},"Currency":{"color":"#fff"}};
  (function (){
    var appName = encodeURIComponent(window.location.hostname);
    if(appName==""){appName="local";}
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = true;
    var theUrl = baseUrl+'serve/v3/coin/header?fsyms=BTC,ETH,XMR,LTC,DASH&tsyms=USD,EUR,CNY,GBP';
    s.src = theUrl + ( theUrl.indexOf("?") >= 0 ? "&" : "?") + "app=" + appName;
    embedder.parentNode.appendChild(s);
  })();
</script>
```

If I place it in the code it doesn't work.

Comment: Any errors you can provide people to assist you?

Comment: It doesn't throw any error it just simply doesn't display anything. It should show crypto coins prices. It would be live data about prices. But it not appears on the screen. No error.

Comment: Do you see also no errors using the F12 tooling?

Answer (score 0):

Place your code in another blade file like ´widget.blade.php ´ and then use ´@include('widget')´ at the end of the jumbotron

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Unfortunately still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that i try to place this widget script inside the

app.blade.php

```
<div id="app">
<-- If i place the widget script inside this div i getning error -->
</div>
```

Error:[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:  app.js:32178 
- Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as , as they will not be parsed.
- Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as , as they will not be parsed.

If i place outside  of app div, the widget works fine.